# Exception javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection while sending Java mail

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail

I am getting following exception while I am trying to send mail.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

I am using javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar.I have following settings in my mail.xml

```
mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

Following are configuraiton of my smtp server:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file=server.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=server.key
smtp_use_tls=yes
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel=1
```

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?

Comment: Right, hopefully the message is clear that you're trying to make an SSL connection to a port that's expecting a plain text connection.  There must be more in your application that's configuring which host and port to connect to, that's probably where the problem is.  See all this list of [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).